# How to query multiple tables with same named FK, using a paramater

Tags: sql, sqlite

SqLite:

Let's say I have 3 tables, A,B & C, each with a column unique to it (colA, colB, colC (in fact, each has several columns, but I only want one column from each)) and a Foreign Key column with the same name (let's call it Idx).

Now, let's say that I want to SELECT A.colA, b.colB, c.colC WHERE idx=:idx

That is to say, I want to pass Idx as a parameter to the query.

That's my question: what is the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways, but I think the best way is to explicitly join the query and then check for the `id` in a `where` clause:

```
SELECT A.colA, b.colB, c.colC
FROM A join
     B
     on A.idx = B.idx join
     C
     on A.idx = C.idx
WHERE A.idx = :idx;
```

This uses `inner join`, under the assumption that the `id` is in all three tables.

Note that if there are multiple rows with the `idx` value in any of the tables, then you'll get multiple rows from the query.